# Multiap-Like Structure in C++ With Database-Like Lookups

Tags: c++, data-structures, multimap

I would like to find (or implement) a structure in C++ which map multiple items to a key (like a multimap), but which can be queried with multiple "and-ed" keys (like a database). For the sake of discussion, I'll call it a querymap. My question is: does such a thing exist? If not, do you have any suggestions for an implementation?

---

Here's an example to clarify the concept. Say I have the following data:

```
Key-1   Key-2   Key-3   Value
'a'                     'A'
'a'                     'B'
'a'     'b'             'C'
'b'                     'D'
'b'     'c'             'E'
'a'     'b'     'c'     'F'
```

Following the syntax of the STL multimap, this data could be stored in a theoretical querymap like so

```
querymap<char, char> qm;
qm.insert(pair<char, char>('a', 'A'));
qm.insert(pair<char, char>('a', 'B'));
qm.insert(pair<char, char>('a', 'C'));
qm.insert(pair<char, char>('b', 'C'));
qm.insert(pair<char, char>('b', 'D'));
qm.insert(pair<char, char>('b', 'E'));
qm.insert(pair<char, char>('c', 'E'));
qm.insert(pair<char, char>('a', 'F'));
qm.insert(pair<char, char>('b', 'F'));
qm.insert(pair<char, char>('c', 'F'));
```

Then to retrieve all elements keyed by `key` key, you call `find(key)`, which returns an iterator for those elements.

```
qm.find('a');
>>> 'A', 'B', 'C', 'F'

qm.find('b');
>>> 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'

qm.find('c');
>>> 'E', 'F'
```

So far this is exactly the behavior of a multimap. A querymap as I currently conceive it, would extend the look-up function to return an iterator for all items which are keyed by all of a *set* of keys. I propose the following syntax, which could be achieved by use of variable argument lists.

```
qm.find('a', 'b');
>>> 'C', 'F'

qm.find('b', 'c');
>>> 'E', 'F'

qm.find('a', 'b', 'c');
>>> 'F'
```

---

My first idea at an implementation was a structure which would internally store a map keyed by a set, with a custom comparison function which would count right-hand sets as equal to their left-hand subsets (must be an asymmetric comparison so that large query sets don't return all of their subsets).

Alternative to setting a custom comparison function would be using a multimap and keying an entry by every possible set of keys with which it should be associated.

Neither of these solutions seem ideal to me. Any thoughts?

Comment: What about a [Boost MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/index.html) container? You can do [composite keys](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/key_extraction.html#composite_keys) that should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Karl! That looks like it's pretty close (if not exactly) to what I was looking for. Not sure how I missed it when I was searching for a solution.

Comment: Actually, I had the chance to check out boost composite keys, and they're close, but not quite what I'm looking for. I need to be able to key by a variable number of columns, all of which are the same type, not a constant number of columns of various types.

Thanks all the same :)